# is this functional dependency derivation correct?

Tags: sql, normalization

Let's say, I have two functional dependencies

```
A -> EF
B -> GH
```

Is there any axiom through which we can deduce the relationship below?

```
AB -> EFGH
```

Comment: If `A` and `B` are unique or `A + B` is Unique then concatenate the `A` and `B` to one column then Concatenate `EF` and `GH` in one column, then try to define relationship between these two column. Also mention which Database engine you are using

Answer (score 2):

You can derive:

```
AB -> EFGH
```

from:

```
A -> EF
B -> GH
```

with the following steps:

```
1.  A -> EF       (by hypothesis)
2.  B -> GH       (by hypothesis)
3.  AB -> BEF     (by augmentation, adding B to the left and right part of 1)
4.  AB -> AGH     (by augmentation, adding A to the left and right part of 2)
5.  AB -> ABEFGH  (by union)
6.  AB -> EFGH    (by decomposition)
```

using the [Armstrong Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms), both base axioms (augmentation) and derived ones (union, decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about what are you trying to do.

But using sick sample I can relate to my work with geographic data because have something similar

I have startpoint `Sp` and endpoint `Ep`

```
 Sp -> x1y1
 Ep -> x2y2
```

And I have a line and in this case `SpEp` is unique

```
 SpEp -> x1y1x2y2
```

But at that moment `SpEp`  become `line_id`

But I hardly will call this an axiom.